# Not able to run basic program on appium

Tags: java, windows, selenium, appium, appium-android

```
 package first;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class auto1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File f = new File("src");
        File fs = new File(f,"DemoAndroid.apk");
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"rahulemulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

    }
```

}

### =====================
**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JIA4NSC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JIA4NSC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at first.auto1.main(auto1.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JIA4NSC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 19 more
```

=======================

Appium is also running

i tried with command appium --avd rahulandroid
Virtual device is also running
i also tried running appium on adminstrator

logs

============

```
POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\eclipse-workspace\\first\\src\\Spectra(Android).apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"rahulemulator"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\eclipse-workspace\\first\\src\\Spectra(Android).apk","appium:deviceName":"rahulemulator","platformName":"android"}]}}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\eclipse-workspace\\first\\src\\Spectra(Android).apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"rahulemulator"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\eclipse-workspace\\first\\src\\Spectra(Android).apk","appium:deviceName":"rahulemulator","platformName":"android"}]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1595960147399 (23:45:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix:
[BaseDriver]   avd
[Appium]
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium]   DEPRECATION WARNING:
[Appium]
[Appium]   The 'automationName' capability was not provided in the desired
[Appium]   capabilities for this Android session
[Appium]
[Appium]   Setting 'automationName=UiAutomator2' by default and using the
[Appium]   UiAutomator2 Driver
[Appium]
[Appium]   The next major version of Appium (2.x) will **require** the
[Appium]   'automationName' capability to be set for all sessions on all
[Appium]   platforms
[Appium]
[Appium]   In previous versions (Appium <= 1.13.x), the default was
[Appium]   'automationName=UiAutomator1'
[Appium]
[Appium]   If you wish to use that automation instead of UiAutomator2, please
[Appium]   add 'automationName=UiAutomator1' to your desired capabilities
[Appium]
[Appium]   For more information about drivers, please visit
[Appium]   http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/intro/ and explore the
[Appium]   'Drivers' menu
[Appium]
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium]
[Appium] Appium v1.17.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.44.2) session
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:avd": "rahulandroid",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\eclipse-workspace\\first\\src\\Spectra(Android).apk",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "rahulemulator"
[debug] [BaseDriver]   },
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
[debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: f540c68d-7e46-4e97-bc3d-0f419c9853df
[BaseDriver] Using local app 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\eclipse-workspace\first\src\Spectra(Android).apk'
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] Found 1 'build-tools' folders under 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' (newest first):
[ADB]     C:/Users/Akanksha Agarwal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.0
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find 'rahulandroid' emulator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5556","state":"device"}]
[debug] [ADB] 1 emulator(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
[debug] [ADB] Getting running emulator port
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device created
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device ready
[debug] [ADB] Telnet command got response: rahulandroid
[debug] [ADB] Found emulator 'rahulandroid' on port 5556
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5556
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not launching AVD because it is already running.
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5556
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5556
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 28
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 9
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 28
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy 1'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
[ADB] Package name: 'com.spectra.consumer'
[ADB] Main activity name: 'com.spectra.consumer.Activities.SplashActivity'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: com.spectra.consumer/com.spectra.consumer.Activities.SplashActivity
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 wait-for-device'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell echo ping'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.1.0' >= '3.1.0')
[debug] [ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[debug] [ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to 8200
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 forward tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790'
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is not installed
[debug] [ADB] App 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is not installed
[debug] [UiAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server installation state: notInstalled
[debug] [ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk
[ADB] Using 'apksigner.jar' from 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\lib\apksigner.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12"\\bin\\java.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\30.0.0\\lib\\apksigner.jar' verify --print-certs 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk'
[ADB] Cannot use apksigner tool for signature verification. Original error: Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
[debug] [ADB] Defaulting to verify.jar
[debug] [ADB] 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is not signed with the default certificate
[debug] [ADB] Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
[ADB] Using 'zipalign.exe' from 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\zipalign.exe'
[debug] [ADB] C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is already zip-aligned. Doing nothing
[debug] [ADB] Signing 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' with default cert
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12"\\bin\\java.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\30.0.0\\lib\\apksigner.jar' sign --key 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\keys\\testkey.pk8' --cert 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\keys\\testkey.x509.pem' 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk'
[ADB] Cannot use apksigner tool for signing. Defaulting to sign.jar. Original error: Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
[debug] [ADB] Starting sign.jar: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12"\\bin\\java.exe' -jar 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\sign.jar' 'C:\\Users\\Akanksha Agarwal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' --override
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[UiAutomator2] Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without session id
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell am force-stop com.spectra.consumer'
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1595960150494 (23:45:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
[debug] [W3C]     at ADB.signWithDefaultCert (C:\Users\Akanksha Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-signing.js:81:13)
[debug] [W3C] Destroying socket connection
```

---

These are the logs which are generated while running the script
i am not able to understand the logs and error

Answer (score 0):

Check the original error in your logs:

```
Original error Command 'C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
```

Make sure you set [env variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-792499849.html) for Java

Comment: I have downloaded new java jdk and set env path in JAVA_HOME and PATH , but still i am getting the same error

Comment: can you confirm that path is the one you got in error? C:\Windows\system32\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12"\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
    package SirichandanaAcademy.Appium;

import java.io.IOException;
//import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.*;

public class AppiumTest1 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
    
        public static void openCalculator(){
        //  public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","Pixel 2 API UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox");
        cap.setCapability("udid","emulator-5554");
        cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","14");  
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.AndroidTest");
    }
    
    
@Test   
    public void appiumtest() throws IOException   
    {
        //androiddriver
        //appium code --> appium server --> mobile
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setPlatformName("Android");
        options.setDeviceName("Pixel 2 API UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox");
        options.setApp("//Appium//src//test//java//Resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk");
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("172.23.210.190:4723"),options);
        driver.getCapabilities();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Perhaps you can explain how your code fixes the error in the code in the question?